# Show Dialog in Game with canvas

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, surfaceview

After finding that starting a new intent might not be the right way to notify user of GameOver, I'm now struggeling with runOnUiThread, Runnable and dialogs..

Question : How and where would I implement a Dialog.show() to notify the user that the game has ended? In my Log, it all works fine (so I managed to get the message Game end when it's supposed to). At some point, boolean GameManger.LevelEnded switches to true. When that happens, I want to show the Dialog..

I've experimented with runOnUiThread, Runnable and Async threads. Can't figure it out.

I have a game. Activity AppelzActivity :

```
public class AppelzActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String TAG = AppelzActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(null);

        // requesting to turn the title OFF
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // set our MainGamePanel as the View
        setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));
        Log.d(TAG, "View added");
    }
}
```

My MainGamePanel class :

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
SurfaceHolder.Callback {

// DECLARING VARS (REMOVED FOR READABILITY)

    public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
        .getDefaultDisplay();
        GameManager.panel = this;

        width = display.getWidth();
        height = display.getHeight();
        RectScreen.set(0,0,width,height);

        // CREATING CONTROLS, MISSION AND VISIBLE OBJECTS (REMOVED FOR READABILITY)

        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setRunning(true);
    }

        // HANDELING ON TOUCH EVENTS AND SUCH (REMOVED FOR READABILITY)


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // fills the canvas with black
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        backGnd.draw(canvas);

        basket.draw(canvas);
        for (int i = 0; i < AppleList.size();i++){
            AppleList.get(i).draw(canvas);
        }
        btnMoreFruit.draw(canvas);
        btnLessFruit.draw(canvas);

        if (GameManager.count){

            glyphsCount.drawString(MainThread.canvas, Integer.toString(GameManager.i), (width/2-120), (height/2-120));

        }

    }
}
```

And finally, the MainThread class :

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private MainGamePanel gamePanel;
    private DialogManager dialogManager;
    public static boolean running;
    public static Canvas canvas;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        MainThread.running = running;
    }

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
        this.dialogManager = dialogManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Canvas canvas;
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
        while (running) {
            MainThread.canvas = null;
            // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing on the surface

            try {
                MainThread.canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    // update game state
                    this.gamePanel.update();

                    // render state to the screen
                    // draws the canvas on the panel
                    this.gamePanel.onDraw(MainThread.canvas);

                }
            } finally {
                // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
                // an inconsistent state
                if (MainThread.canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(MainThread.canvas);
                }
            } // end finally
        }
    }
}
```

Basket.java - This is an object in the game. As you can see, if it is in a certain position, I start a CountDown :

```
public class basket {

 private Bitmap bitmap; // the actual bitmap
 private int x;   // the X coordinate
 private int y;   // the Y coordinate'
 public static int width;
 public static int height;
 public float X = 100;
 public float Y = 100;

 private boolean touched; // if droid is touched/picked up

 public basket(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
  this.bitmap = bitmap;

  width = bitmap.getWidth(); 
  height = bitmap.getHeight(); 
 }

 public Bitmap getBitmap() {
  return bitmap;
 }
 public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
  this.bitmap = bitmap;
 }

 public int getWidth(){
      return bitmap.getWidth();
     }

     public int getHeight(){
      return bitmap.getHeight();
     }

 public int getX() {
  return x;
 }



 public void setX(float x) {

    // if basket is further than slotmargin 
     if (x + width/2 > SlotManager.SlotmarginX) {
        // if basket is NOT in CheckOut area    
         if (this.Y < MainGamePanel.height - 80 - height/2){
            x = SlotManager.SlotmarginX - width/2;

        } else {
            // if basket IS in CheckOut area
            x = MainGamePanel.width - width/2;

            // Start the countdown timer if not already running
            if (!GameManager.count){
                GameManager.count=true;
// --- HERE I START COUNTDOWN
                GameManager.handler.postDelayed(GameManager.runnable, 0);                               
            }

        }
    } else {

        // Basket is NOT in CheckOut area; stop countdown timer
        GameManager.count=false;
    }

     this.X = x;
 }


 public int getY() {
  return y;
 }
 public void setY(int y) {
        if (y + height/2 > MainGamePanel.height - 80){
            y = MainGamePanel.height - 80 - height/2;
        }


  this.Y = y;
 }


 public boolean isTouched() {
  return touched;
 }

 public void setTouched(boolean touched) {
  this.touched = touched;
 }

 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, X - width/2, Y - height/2, null);
 }

 public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY) {
  if (eventX >= (X - width/ 2) && (eventX <= (X + width/2))) {
   if (eventY >= (Y - height/ 2) && (eventY <= (Y + height/ 2))) {
    // basket touched
    setTouched(true);
   } else {
    setTouched(false);
   }
  } else {
   setTouched(false);
  }

 }
}
```

The CountDown in GameManager is :

```
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (SlotManager.alSlottedFruitList.size() > 0){
            //TODO Create Full screen countdown timer
                Log.d("", "Countdown Timer in GameManager " + i);

                i--;
                if (count && i > -1) // stop timer when count is false
                {
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                } else {
                    if (i == -1){
                        Log.d("", "RoundUp the Level");

// --- HERE I WANT TO DO A LEVEL END AND SHOW THE DIALOG                        

                    }
                    // reset Countdown (if basket outside checkout)
                    i = 6;
                }
            } else {
                // reset Countdown (if slot has no fruits)
                i = 6;
            }
        }
    };

    public static void startCountDown() {
        handler.postDelayed(GameManager.runnable, 0);
    }

    public static void finishRound() {
        listener.onRoundFinished();
    }



    public static List<Integer> missionlist;

    public static void CreateMission(){
        int maxtotalitems = 6;
        missionlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random Rnd = new Random();

        for (int FruitType = 0; FruitType < FruitManager.fruitResources.size();FruitType++){
            for (int x = 0; x < Rnd.nextInt(maxtotalitems); x++){
                missionlist.add(FruitType); 
            }}

// --- HERE I WANT TO SHOW A DIALOG CONTAINING THE MISSION


        for (int x = 0; x < FruitManager.fruitResources.size();x++){
            Log.d("MISSION", "Mission for " + x + " : " + Collections.frequency(missionlist, x));
        }

// Let's show the Dialog containing the mission 

    }

    public void LevelEnd(){
        // First, count the Fruits in the slot
        SlotManager.countSlotInv();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();      
        // Fill itemIds with the types of fruits
        for (apple a : SlotManager.alSlottedFruitList){
            Integer itemId = Integer.valueOf(a.FruitType);
            list.add(itemId);
        }


            for (int key = 0; key < 3 ; key++) {
                boolean succeed = CheckMissionComplete(key, Collections.frequency(list, key));

                System.out.println(key + " : " + Collections.frequency(list, key));
                    Log.d("MISSION", "Number : " + key + " : succeed = " + succeed );                   
            }
            listener.onRoundFinished();
    }

    public boolean CheckMissionComplete(int key, int amount) {

        //CheckMission
        if (amount == Collections.frequency(missionlist, key)){
            return true;            
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }

    public GameManager(GameListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }





}
```

Comment: can you please mention a line where you want dialog box exactly

Comment: Sameer, I've added the class Basket. It is an object in the game. If you put the basket in a specific location, countdown starts. If countdown is finished (5 seconds), I start a routine to check user input against the given mission. Then, I want to show the dialog. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are calling post invalidate from Thread so you can not show dialog.For showing dialog the basic need is activity context.and second it can display directly inside thread so when your condition satisfied pick context of activity from surface view class and take one handler then show dialog box.

Comment: Can you please explain what happens when you do `runOnUIThread()` and other approaches you tried..?

Comment: Please add the code that doesnt work and comment it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to keep it simple. Hold a reference to the context in your `GameManager` class. Use it to display your dialog.

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
                                   SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
   .......
    GameManager.panel = this;
    GameManager.context = context; // add a reference to the context in GameManager..
   ........
   ........

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

In your `GameManager` use it to call `runOnUIThread()`

```
 Activity context;  // Context of the main activity..
 ........
 @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (SlotManager.alSlottedFruitList.size() > 0){
        //TODO Create Full screen countdown timer
            Log.d("", "Countdown Timer in GameManager " + i);

            i--;
            if (count && i > -1) // stop timer when count is false
            {
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            } else {
                if (i == -1){
                    Log.d("", "RoundUp the Level");

// --- HERE I WANT TO DO A LEVEL END AND SHOW THE DIALOG    

                    context.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {   // Use the context here
                        @override
                        public void run() {
                            showLevelEndDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // reset Countdown (if basket outside checkout)
                i = 6;
            }
        } else {
            // reset Countdown (if slot has no fruits)
            i = 6;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I get an error : "The method runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: Just change the reference type of `GameManager.context` to `Activity` instead of `Context`...

Comment: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Context to Activity" -- hmm.. I'm also thinking; in different parts of the game, I want the controls to behave differently. So.. Not just the displaying of items, but also the OnTouchEvents. I might want to implement a different solution entirely?

Comment: Let the `MainGamePanel` constructor receive a `Activity` object instead of a Context..

Comment: I got this working! Thanks userSeven7s!.. I used the Dialog method. I got a hint to use the Fragment thingie (?).. but got a lot of errors on that, so I'll try that some other time.. for now, I'm back on track, by implementing this suggestion.

Comment: userSeven7s, thanks to your answer I was able to write https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=happyworx.nl.Applez . Thank you!

Comment: Only problem is that the dialog is out of focus

Comment: I have the same problem, it does nothing, i don't  even get an error. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

I think, the simplest way is to introduce the callback mechanism through listeners. To do so, add a listener interface (e.g., `GameListener.java`), hold reference to the instance of this interface and invoke its methods in the class, where all your game logic appears (let's say `Game.java`). Then, let your `AppelzActivity` implement this interface and show dialog when appropriate callback is called:

**`GameListener.java`**:

```
public interface GameListener {
    /** 
    * ...
    * NOTE: may be called on any thread
    */
    public void onRoundFinished();
    ...
}
```

**`Game.java`**:

```
public class Game {
    private GameListener listener;

    public Game(GameListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    ...

    //Let's say, round finishes here
    public void finishRound() {
        ...

        listener.onRoundFinished();
    }
}
```

**`AppelzActivity.java`**:

```
public class AppelzActivity extends Activity implements GameListener {

    private static final int DLG_ROUND_FINISHED = 1;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onRoundFinished() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showDialog(DLG_ROUND_FINISHED);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
        case DLG_ROUND_FINISHED:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            ... // init your dialog here

            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. I don't know what you mean by "invoke its methods in the class, where all your game logic appears (let's say Game.java)". The basket object triggers the countdown (in GameManager) when countdown hits zero, then the dialog should be shown. I still get the null pointer exeption if I try to call Game.finishRound() from the GameManager class? Also, I don't know how to initialize game in that class? .. feeling this is the right way to go, but can't implement. Do you know any tutorials about "the game logic" ? thnx!!!

Comment: Do you think this would be a feasible approach? http://www.benareby.com/tutorial/ch36

Comment: Here: _basket object triggers the countdown (in GameManager) when countdown hits zero_ you need to call `listener.onRoundFinished()` in the `GameManager` (in my example it's `Game.java`). Actually, this is general Java approach, not game-specific, so I'd start from some Java textbook.

Comment: Just to clear things up: you do exactly what a.ch.said and add this: the activity which encloses the class (with the method setListener(Listener listen)) implements Listener and in it's oncreate or onResume or where-ever you call yourClass.setListener(this).

Comment: However this answer is still better then the accepted answer.